# Connecting on linux desktop but printing on windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, fedora, printing

Does anyone know how can I connect to Linux machine in another network from windows, use some software on it, but print on local printer on that windows machine.

I know it's possible with microsoft's RDP, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with Linux?

Comment: Why can't you put your printer online? If you do, the printer will be accessible from the whole LAN.

Comment: It is on different LAN, and in different company, different building...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the linux client is on a remote network and that the printer is directly connected to your local windows client, connect the two machines via vpn, then add your local windows printer on linux trough a "shared printer" connection.

Answer (score 0):

[Thinlinc](https://www.cendio.com/resources/docs/tag/printing.html) apparently has a feature to allow you to print to local printers.

Answer (score 0):

If printing from Google Chrome consider Google Cloud Print.  Normally the printer must be network connected and relatively new to support it but a "classic" (old) printer connected by USB to a Windows machine can still work:

https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en